# fopen() working with windows but giving issues in linux

Tags: c++, linux, file, fopen

I am trying to use `fopen()` in a program in which I am creating a new file and then using that file into another function. The function is created as follows:-

```
FILE* check=NULL;
check =fopen(convert_wchartoString(file_Name.c_str()).c_str(), "rb");
if(check==NULL)
{
  cout<<"Unable to open";
}
```

Now, the issue is that fopen is returning NULL in linux but, in windows it is working. I am not sure why this issue is coming. I have debugged the value of `file_name` and it is coming fine on both the platforms. Please advice something which could be potentially wrong in this?

**UPDATE:-**

Seems like it is a path issue. Currently, the `file_name` has path to `C:\files` but when i try to run the same code in wsl, it doesn't work. The path in wsl is `/mnt/c/files`. But when trying to give this path to `file_name`. It is also not working. Is there any permission issues for the same or should I need to modify the path?

Comment: Linux (and Unix OSs for that matter) don't make use of `wchar` type. Whatever `convert_wchartoString` does, it's most likely responsible for the issue you're experiencing. I suggest you just use `file_Name.c_str()` for the path parameter of fopen, rather than doing the conversion.

Comment: It may also depend on the path of the file. Not all paths that are valid on windows are valid on Linux. What is the full path of the file you are trying to open.

Comment: What is `file_Name`? What is `convert_wchartoString`? Pleae show more code.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `FILE* check = NULL; check = fopen(...);` should be a single statement: `FILE* check = fopen(...);`.

Comment: @PeteBecker: In this case it doesn't matter, every compiler will optimize away the initialization of `check` with a null pointer. It would be a different story, if it was `FILE *const check = …`.

Comment: @datenwolf -- it might not affect the generated code in this case, but it's a good habit, both because it often **will** matter, and because it will avoid having people like me point out that the initialization is pointless.